# I am getting an Error : list index out of range while working on my python project .

Tags: python

I wrote this code to display contents of a list in grid form . 
It works fine for the alphabet list . 
But when i try to run it with a randomly generated list it gives an list index out of range error .

Here is the full code:
    import random

```
#barebones 2d shell grid generator



'''
Following list is a place holder
you can add any list data to show in a grid pattern with this tool
'''
lis = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

newLis = []
#generates random list
def lisGen():
    length = 20 # random.randint(10,20)
    for i in range(length):
        value = random.randint(1,9)
        newLis.append(str(value))

lisGen()

askRow = input('Enter number of rows :')
askColumns = input('Enter number of columns :')



def gridGen(row,column):
    j=0

    cnt = int(row)
    while (cnt>0):

        for i in range(int(column)):
            print(' '+'-',end='')
        print('\n',end='')
#this is the output content loop
        for i in range(int(column)):
            if j<len(lis):
                print('|'+newLis[j],end='')
                j += 1
            else:
                print('|'+' ',end='')

        print('|',end='')
        print('\n',end='')
        cnt -= 1

    for i in range(int(column)):
        print(' '+'-',end='')
    print('\n',end='')




gridGen(askRow,askColumns)
```

The expected/correct output ,using the alphabet list(lis):

```
Enter number of rows :7
Enter number of columns :7
 - - - - - - -
|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|
 - - - - - - -
|h|j|i|j|k|l|m|
 - - - - - - -
|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|
 - - - - - - -
|u|v|w|x|y|z| |
 - - - - - - -
| | | | | | | |
 - - - - - - -
| | | | | | | |
 - - - - - - -
| | | | | | | |
 - - - - - - -
```

The error output when used randomly generated list ( newLis ):

```
Enter number of rows :7
Enter number of columns :7
 - - - - - - -
|9|2|1|4|7|5|4|
 - - - - - - -
|9|7|7|3|2|1|3|
 - - - - - - -
|7|5|4|1|2|3Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\01-Mywares\python\2d shell graphics\gridGen.py", line 56, in <module>
    gridGen(askRow,askColumns)
  File "D:\01-Mywares\python\2d shell graphics\gridGen.py", line 40, in gridGen
    print('|'+newLis[j],end='')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You are checking `if j<len(lis):` but accessing `newLis`, so it's no surprise you are getting a `IndexError`, since your `newLis` is shorter than `lis`.

Comment: Ah i missed it , thankyou for the help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `gridGen` function is indexing into `newLis` but it's testing the size of `lis` instead of `newLis`. It would be a much better design if you pass `gridGen` the list that you want to print rather than having it access the global `newLis`. That would make the code easier to read, and reduce the odds of doing mistakes like that. Similarly, `lisGen` should create a local list and return it, rather than mutating the global `newLis`.

Your `gridGen` is way more complicated than it needs to be. We can simplify it by creating an iterator of the list we want to print and calling the `next` function on that iterator. We give `next` a default arg of `' '` - a string containing a single space char, so when the list runs out of items `next` will return the blank space.

Rather than printing the strings one by one we build each row in a list comprehension and then join the strings in the row into a single string.

Here's my version of your program. I've changed the names to make them conform to the PEP-8 style guide.

```
import random

random.seed(42)

def lis_gen():
    newlis = []
    length = 20
    for i in range(length):
        value = random.randint(1,9)
        newlis.append(str(value))
    return newlis

def grid_gen(lis, rows, cols):
    it = iter(lis)

    # Horizontal line
    hline = ' -' * cols
    print(hline)
    for j in range(rows):
        line = '|'.join([next(it, ' ') for i in range(cols)])
        print('|' + line + '|')
        print(hline)

ask_rows = 5
ask_cols = 7

alpha = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
grid_gen(alpha, ask_rows, ask_cols)
print()

newlis = lis_gen()
grid_gen(newlis, ask_rows, ask_cols)
```

**output**

```
 - - - - - - -
|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|
 - - - - - - -
|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|
 - - - - - - -
|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|
 - - - - - - -
|v|w|x|y|z| | |
 - - - - - - -
| | | | | | | |
 - - - - - - -

 - - - - - - -
|2|1|5|4|4|3|2|
 - - - - - - -
|9|2|7|1|1|2|4|
 - - - - - - -
|4|9|1|9|4|9| |
 - - - - - - -
| | | | | | | |
 - - - - - - -
| | | | | | | |
 - - - - - - -
```

Note that we really don't need to do `alpha = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')` here: if we pass `grid_gen` a string instead of a list it will iterate over each char in the string.

---

There's room for improvement in `grid_gen`. With a little more work we can make it neatly print out strings that contain more than one char. The first step is to scan the input list to find the length of the longest string it contains. If `lis` is a list of strings we can do that with

```
maxlen = max(map(len, lis))
```

Comment: Wow man that was great explanation and improvement to my code. Really thankyou for this :D . That line method is great and talking about the grid_len improvement yes i plan to do that using your maxlen method and try multi digit outputs .

Answer (score 0):

Problem with lisGen function, it is generating fixed number of items for list (i.e 20 in your case). It should be row * cols.

[This is the link for updated code](https://repl.it/H1WF/0)